# If-else vs if not-if

Tags: if-statement, standards

According to a lead at work, the distinction between

```
if (invalid) {
   ...some code
}

if (!invalid) {
  ...some code
}
```

and

```
if (invalid) {
  ...some code
} else {
  ...some code
}
```

can be interpreted as a style choice. I was wondering where people draw the line and what you would consider this.

PS: Yes, I know negations should not be the 'nominal' case for if statements. Please ignore that as I was trying to replicate exactly the code in question that prompted the discussion.

Comment: If `invalid` can be modified within first block, or can be modified in another thread, then the two approaches are certainly not equivalent. To me the first one is unequivocally worse, always use if-else.

Comment: If i not wrong, in the second case, your algoritm make only one comparation, its generate less process time.

Comment: In any case I'd probably go for `if {} else {}` so that I don't have to repeat condition and inverse it. Also - condition could be a computation and more complex than a simple boolean field.

Comment: Unless this is in C++ or another language that allows for overriding negation, they should be the same. The former is certainly less clear though, as it allows for the possibility of a third case on a quick read over, whereas the latter clearly only allows for two possible cases

Comment: your lead is bad :p
this is not the same code, as invalid could indeed be modified. If it is then fine, but different code
if not, it is a double test, is less readable and prevent reading the flow

Comment: They are clearly not equivalent when the first `if()` statement modifies the value of `invalid`.

Comment: @Dipstick In my case, there is NO overriding whatsoever, all contained code is agnostic, both statements follow each other

Comment: It's not just a style choice. It can affect code validity, as per my answer, without the condition changing at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only is there redundancy here, but depending on the language, there can also be a difference in correctness/validity. Consider this C# code:

```
int value;
bool condition = DateTime.UtcNow.Second < 30;
if (condition)
{
    value = 10;
}
else            
{
    value = 20;
}
// No problem, value is definitely assigned
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

That's entirely valid. But if we write it in the redundant style, we'll get a compile-time error:

```
int value;
bool condition = DateTime.UtcNow.Second < 30;
if (condition)
{
    value = 10;
}
if (!condition)
{
    value = 20;
}
// error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'value'
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

The same would be true in Java, and I suspect in many other languages as well. The compiler can take account of the fact that in `if`/`else`, execution will flow into exactly one of those branches. In the "two if statements" style, the language rules don't make that guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a style choice.

If you have two separate `if`s, then the expression is effectively evaluated twice. The expression can be complex, it can even be a method, that method can have side-effects:

```
if (someMethod()) {
}

if (!someMethod()) {
}
```

The difference should be obvious.

Also note that `if-else` makes a difference to the compiler because the compiler can be sure that exactly one of the two paths can be executed. That has consequences for detecting unreachable code, uninitialized variables and similar cases.

Usually the compiler cannot detect the same situation with two separate `if`s.